# Can't access internet or ping default gateway from a FreeBSD 12 jail

Tags: networking, virtualbox, freebsd, chroot-jail

I am new to FreeBSD jails, everything (such as ssh to jail from any host in network) works fine except I can't access internet or ping default gateway from a FreeBSD 12 jail, please help me to resolve this

**Update** : I was able to resolve the issue by enabling IPv6 and I can access any IPv6 enabled host from jails

my setup as follows

- a laptop running on Ubuntu 16.04.4/ Kernel 4.15.0-29-generic (172.20.0.2) is connector to 4G router (172.20.0.1) via wlan0
- VirtualBox ver 5.2.16 r123759 installed on the system
- FreeBSD 12 is running on VirtualBox with Bridged adapter to wlan0
- a Jail running on FreeBSD 12

diagram:

```
+-------------------------------+
|   E5172Bs-925 4G router       |
|                               |
+-------------------------------+
              |172.20.0.1
              |
              |
              |
              |
              |
 wlan0        |172.20.0.2 gw: 172.20.0.1      Ubuntu 16.04.4/ Kernel 4.15.0-29-generic
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|             |                                                 |
|             |                                                 |
|             |                                                 |
| FreeBSD 12  |172.20.0.41 (Attached to Bridged adapter)        |
| +-----------+gw: 172.20.0.1---+---------------+               |
| |                             |               |               |
| |                             |               |               |
| |                             |               |               |
| | +---------------------------+--------+      |               |
| | | jail : 172.20.0.110                |      |               |
| | | gw: 172.20.0.1                     |      |               |
| | |                                    |      |               |
| | |                                    |      |               |
| | |                                    |      |               |
| | |                                    |      |               |
| | +------------------------------------+      |               |
| |                                             |               |
| +---------------------------------------------+               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

my jail.conf file (got from /usr/share/examples/jails/jail.xxx.conf)

```
rsnapshot {
    host.hostname = "rsnapshot";    # hostname
    path = "/jails/rsnapshot";              # root directory

    exec.clean;
    exec.system_user = "root";
    exec.jail_user = "root";

    #
    # NB: Below 4-lines required
    #
    vnet;
    # netgraph
    #vnet.interface = "ng0_rsnapshot";               # vnet interface(s)
    #exec.prestart += "jng bridge rsnapshot em0";    # bridge interface(s)
    #exec.poststop += "jng shutdown rsnapshot";      # destroy interface(s)
    # if_bridge
    vnet.interface = "e0b_rsnapshot";              # vnet interface(s)
    exec.prestart += "jib addm rsnapshot em0";     # bridge interface(s)
    exec.poststop += "jib destroy rsnapshot";      # destroy interface(s)

    # Standard recipe
    exec.start += "/bin/sh /etc/rc";
    exec.stop = "/bin/sh /etc/rc.shutdown";
    exec.consolelog = "/var/log/jail_rsnapshot_console.log";
    mount.devfs;    # mount devfs

    # Optional (default off)
    #devfs_ruleset = "11";          # rule to unhide bpf for DHCP
    #allow.mount;                   # mount /etc/fstab.rsnapshot
    #allow.set_hostname = 1;        # Allow hostname to change
    #allow.sysvipc = 1;             # Allow SysV Interprocess Comm.
```

}

host ifconfig

```
    em0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=810099<RXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,VLAN_HWFILTER>
    ether 08:00:27:9b:b8:c4
    inet 172.20.0.41 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.20.0.255 
    media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x2 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    groups: lo 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
em0bridge: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    ether 02:d7:f0:96:d8:00
    id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 hellotime 2 fwddelay 15
    maxage 20 holdcnt 6 proto rstp maxaddr 2000 timeout 1200
    root id 00:00:00:00:00:00 priority 32768 ifcost 0 port 0
    member: e0a_rsnapshot flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 4 priority 128 path cost 2000
    member: em0 flags=143<LEARNING,DISCOVER,AUTOEDGE,AUTOPTP>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 1 priority 128 path cost 20000
    groups: bridge 
    nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
e0a_rsnapshot: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 02:f8:e0:9b:b8:c4
    hwaddr 02:70:c5:28:c6:0a
    groups: epair 
    media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T (10Gbase-T <full-duplex>)
    status: active
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

jail's ifconfig

```
    lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
    options=680003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,LINKSTATE,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    groups: lo 
    nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
e0b_rsnapshot: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
    options=8<VLAN_MTU>
    ether 0e:f8:e0:9b:b8:c4
    hwaddr 02:70:c5:28:c6:0b
    inet 172.20.0.110 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 172.20.0.255 
    groups: epair 
    media: Ethernet 10Gbase-T (10Gbase-T <full-duplex>)
    status: active
    nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

I can ping to to any host in my network from jail but not default getaway or outside

tcpdump of wlan0 of my laptop shows as below, I can see ICMP echo request but no replies

```
    11:03:40.748008 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52840, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.20.0.110 > 172.20.0.1: ICMP echo request, id 45323, seq 0, length 64
11:03:40.775639 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Request who-has 172.20.0.110 tell 172.20.0.1, length 28
11:03:40.776034 ARP, Ethernet (len 6), IPv4 (len 4), Reply 172.20.0.110 is-at 0e:f8:e0:9b:b8:c4, length 28
```

If i ping my laptop from jail, it shows

```
 11:31:15.625571 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 52842, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.20.0.110 > 172.20.0.2: ICMP echo request, id 6668, seq 0, length 64
11:31:15.625629 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 2336, offset 0, flags [none], proto ICMP (1), length 84)
    172.20.0.2 > 172.20.0.110: ICMP echo reply, id 6668, seq 0, length 64
```

netstat -rn on jail

```
root@freebsdjail1:/ # netstat -rn
Routing tables

Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags     Netif Expire
default            172.20.0.1         UGS    e0b_rsna
127.0.0.1          link#1             UH          lo0
172.20.0.0/24      link#2             U      e0b_rsna
172.20.0.110       link#2             UHS         lo0

Internet6:
Destination                       Gateway                       Flags     Netif Expire
::/96                             ::1                           UGRS        lo0
::1                               link#1                        UH          lo0
::ffff:0.0.0.0/96                 ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::/10                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
fe80::%lo0/64                     link#1                        U           lo0
fe80::1%lo0                       link#1                        UHS         lo0
ff02::/16                         ::1                           UGRS        lo0
```

Comment: You have "VirtualBox with Bridged adapter to wlan0". Is Ubuntu with VirtualBox able to bridge wireless? In addition to this FreeBSD to ping wlan needs "*security.jail.allow_raw_sockets: 1*".

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBotka I believe it's possible to bridge a wireless, My FreeBSD12 (virtualBox guest) can access internet without any issue...   

security.jail.allow_raw_sockets also set to 0
root@fbsd12j:~ # sysctl -a | grep 'allow.raw_sockets'
security.jail.param.allow.raw_sockets: 0
security.jail.allow_raw_sockets: 0

I am not sure this is an issue with my router... there are no way to run tcpdump or other tools on my router as it's a lowend 4G CPE

Comment: It should be "*security.jail.allow_raw_sockets: 1*" to allow ping.

Comment: Thank you @VladimirBotka  I've tried either ways but no luck with Ipv4, I've setup setup ipv6 on the jail, I was able to 'ping6 ipv6.google.com' and access the jail from an outside network... my Ipv6 setup skips the my routers as default GW  but using a tunnel (hurricane electric) setup on my laptop (Linux)...ipv6 is powerful enough for my hobby work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default, FreeBSD does not forward packets across interfaces.  You can tell it that you DO wish to forward packets by setting a `sysctl` value:

```
sysctl net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
```

If that fixes your problem, enable it permanently by doing either:

```
echo 'net.inet.ip.forwarding=1' >> /etc/sysctl.conf
```

or

```
sysrc gateway_enable=1
```

Either command will ensure that IPv4 forwarding is enabled on the next reboot.

Comment: Thank you @Jim L. but I am not intent to use my FreeBSD as a GW to my jails as I used bridging the interfaces in FreeBSD host... I already had IPv4 forwarding enabled on my Linux host